Can binding Source use RelativeSource?
Given two models:
public class Person
{
    public Address Address { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; } = null!;
}

And a page:
<ContentPage.Resources>        
    <vm:Person x:Key="person"
                Address="{vm:Address City='New York'}" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

<VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource person}" x:DataType="vm:Person">
    <Label x:DataType="vm:Address" BindingContext="{Binding Address, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:Person}}}"
            Text="{Binding City}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>

it works as expected.
But why the following does not work?
<VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource person}" x:DataType="vm:Person">
    <Label x:DataType="vm:Address" Text="{Binding City, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:Person}}}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>

Edit
I think it is not about StaticResource. It still does  not work even if I remove StaticResource but use direct instantiation.
<VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{vm:Person Address={vm:Address City='Tokyo'}}" x:DataType="vm:Person">
    <Label x:DataType="vm:Address" Text="{Binding City, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:Person}}}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>


Why would you use a StaticResource for the BindingContext? What's the purpose of this?

Is there an actual problem you're dealing with? Because, yes, in general you can use RelativeSource with Source, but that's usually not done with static resources, because data binding is intended for observable objects. So, what's the point here?

Why do you think you need a RelativeSource here? The BindingContext that you're setting already points to the target object, there is no need to look further up the object tree. The RelativeSource would usually be a parent object higher up in the hierarchy.

Yes, but to what purpose? Even with a static resource or a directly instantiated object, you would simply need to do this: Text="{Binding Address.City}" if you've already set the BindingContext to an instance of Person

Why RelativeSource isn't needed here
You don't need to use the RelativeSource here. That's only used to look up in the object hierarchy.
The following points to the wrong object:
<VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource person}" x:DataType="vm:Person">
    <Label x:DataType="vm:Address" Text="{Binding City, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:Person}}}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>

Here, you actually cannot bind to City, because that's not part of the Person class, it's part of the Address class, but you're not setting up a binding to the Address property of the Person class. Instead, you're trying to directly point from Person to City, which doesn't work, because Person doesn't have a City property.
To visualize, the above tells the binding expression the following:
Label.Text => Person.City

while you actually want
Label.Text => Person.Address.City

So, if your BindingContext already points to the right object (of type Person) and you want to access a child property (down the object hierarchy), all you need to do is access it directly like this:
<VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource person}" x:DataType="vm:Person">
    <Label Text="{Binding Address.City}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>

You don't need to redefine the x:DataType for the Label. The x:DataType just lets the compiler know what type the target object has that you're binding to, which allows to apply compiled bindings. The x:DataType does not participate in the actual resolution of the object graph for the binding expression. That's probably where the confusion comes from.
Sample usage of RelativeSource
The RelativeSource can be used, for example, when you need to look up in the object hierarchy (e.g. binding to an ancestor), as mentioned before. For example, if you have a ViewModel which exposes a collection and a command and you would like to bind the command for each item in the collection:
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Address> Addresses { get; set }

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        Addresses = new()
        {
            new Address() { City = "Berlin" },
            new Address() { City = "Rome" },
            new Address() { City = "Paris" }
        }
    }

    public ICommand TravelCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(TravelToCity);

    private void TravelToCity(string city)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}

This is a situation, where RelativeSource is useful, because we're iterating the collection and in the DataTemplate we're further down in the hierarchy already and can only access the TravelCommand when looking up in the object hierarchy:
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <vm:SomeViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

<CollectionView
    BindingContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"
    x:DataType="vm:SomeViewModel"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}">

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:Address">
            <Button
                Text="{Binding City}"
                Command="{Binding TravelCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:SomeViewModel}}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding City}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>


I think the important part is you need to show an example how to use Source with RelativeSource. Because it is the point of my question. :-)

@DG Not really, that wouldn't be necessary to explain why your code doesn't work, but I showed an example illustrating how to use RelativeSource typically, anyway.

I see.  We can also use CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={RelativeSource Self}}" here.

@DG yes, that should be possible, too, in this particular case

I noticed that x:DataType in Label is mandatory in my first working example: <VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource person}" x:DataType="vm:Person">     <Label x:DataType="vm:Address" BindingContext="{Binding Address, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:Person}}}"             Text="{Binding City}" /> </VerticalStackLayout>
